# Adding existing classes to ecorediagram

Tags: diagram, eclipse-emf, ecore

I want to edit my ecore model in a diagram. I created an `ecorediag` but I cannot find any way to add the existing classes in it. The only way it works is if I use the "Initialize the diagram with existing domain model objects". But if I create new classes or accidentally remove them, there is no way I could add them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag & drop existing elements to the diagram from the Outline view.

Answer (score 1):

Smth's obviously not working right for you because that should be reasonably easy.  Two options I'm aware of:

1. If you reveal the palette (it might be collapsed to a little triangle in the top-left hand corner of your ecorediag), the EClass icon (2nd from top) lets you create a new EClass by drag-dropping it onto the diagram.
2. If this isn't working for some obscure reason, you could go to the ecore model linked to your diagram, right-click an EPackage and select New Child->EClass.  That new class can then be dragged & dropped onto your diagram.

Hope this helps; let me know if not.

Comment: "Smth?" Sorry what do you mean? I'll check if I can drag&drop from the EMF editor. I remember like I tried it but will try again.

Comment: Sorry, 'smth' is short for 'something'.  The drag & drop does take some getting used to but it definitely works.  What version of Eclispe are you on?

Comment: I added a screenshot. D&D does not work for some reason. I'm using Eclipse Juno. ("Smth's" looked like you misspelled Simth's but that didn't make sense at all :) )

Comment: All right, I got it. I can D&D classes from the "Outline" view! What a mess! Removing the entities, however, works as inconsistently as possible. It doesn't feel like this editor has been developed for more than 10 years. It's a shame on them.